# Adding mapview in tablelayout/tablerow at runtime

Tags: android

I know how to use map in application. But I have to use map in particular table row at run time. I have used mapview in my another activity. can I use that map view (by id)
to show map in that row.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to, try it and see.

Comment: Thank You CaseyB,
           I use same MapView which is used in another map. By using findViewById I take that map view. but it giving me unexpectedly close error. can you help me in that.

Comment: CaseyB
       This my few lines of code where i got problem
            tablerow=new TableRow(this);
            MapView mapView=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
            tablerow.addView(mapView);
            innertable.addView(tablerow);  

   that mapView i was used in main page which extend MapActivity.
  but in this page i extend Activity I have to display that area information with that place on map in last row of table.

Comment: Can you post your layout xml and the logcat output after the crash?